# detailViewController.navigationController is always nil

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

Using Xcode 4.x I created a SplitView project for iPad

From RootViewController I'm trying to display a TableView inside detailView by doing this:

[detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:slc animated:YES];

This does not work for me and upon investigation I find that detailViewController.navigationController is always nil

I don't know why this is nil or how to go about making this not nil.

appreciate any help I can get

thanks
Dhoti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:slc animated:YES];
```